# How can I independently use submodule of a module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I wish to use the 'utils-merge' node module already present as a dependency of express 4.12.3. I have express installed in my server application.
I have tried:

```
var merge = require('express/utils-merge');
```

and

```
var merge = require('utils-merge');
```

But it throws error 'Cannot find module'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use relative path to submodule after parent module name (see [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)):

```
var merge = require('express/node_modules/utils-merge');
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do it using:

```
var merge = require('express/node_modules/utils-merge');
```

However, the standard practice is to explicitly require all of your dependencies so that you can directly require them.

Comment: Agreed, use it as a separate dependency instead of using the one that Express depends on.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be simple to use something already existing than having a copy of the same.